# NSXMLParser parsing failure on reuse but no error code

Tags: nsxmlparser, parsing-error

i have  4 NSXMLParser objects.they work fine when i use them for first time but when i use them more than once they fail but return no error code

**initialization**

```
 -(void)initParsers
 {
     NSURL* file_url = nil;
        FOR(i,4){       

    file_url = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:[[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"stack%d",0]ofType:@"xml" inDirectory:@"stackXmls"]];
    stackXmlParser[i] = [[NSXMLParser alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:file_url];
    stackXmlParser[i].delegate = self;
   }   

 }
```

**Parse**

```
BOOL success = [stackXmlParser[currentStack] parse];
if (success)
{
   //Do XML stuff
   ...          
} else {
NSLog(@"Error Error Error!!!");
    NSError *error = [stackXmlParser[currentStack] parserError];
    NSLog(@"Errors with xmlParser: %@  %d", [error localizedDescription], error.code); 
}
```

**OUTPUT**

```
 2012-01-24 16:03:29.542 Cards[5168:207] Error Error Error!!!
 2012-01-24 16:03:29.543 Cards[5168:207] Errors with xmlParser: (null)  0
```

Comment: Any chances it gets released in-between? (sorry if this sounds stupid)

Comment: nope global objects being released in -(void)dealloc of controller

Comment: Okay, and how do you create the parser?

Comment: Try [[NSXMLParser alloc]initWithData:[NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:...]], worked for my simple CLI app (and yes, I was able to reproduce your problem, probably parser reaches the end of the file stream and then there's nothing to parse or something like that)

Comment: @zrxq cool that worked for me why dont you add it as an answer!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using initWithData instead of initWithContentsOfURL

```
NSXMLParser *parser = [[NSXMLParser alloc]initWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL fileURLWithPath:pathToXMLFile]];
NSLog(@"initWithContentsOfURL 1: %s", ([parser parse])?"OK":"Fail");
NSLog(@"initWithContentsOfURL 2: %s", ([parser parse])?"OK":"Fail");
parser = [[NSXMLParser alloc]initWithData:[NSData dataWithContentsOfFile:pathToXMLFile]];
NSLog(@"initWithData 1: %s", ([parser parse])?"OK":"Fail");
NSLog(@"initWithData 2: %s", ([parser parse])?"OK":"Fail");
```

**Output**

```
2012-01-24 18:37:31.260 CLIXMPLParser[12658:707] initWithContentsOfURL 1: OK
2012-01-24 18:37:31.280 CLIXMPLParser[12658:707] initWithContentsOfURL 2: Fail
2012-01-24 18:37:31.292 CLIXMPLParser[12658:707] initWithData 1: OK
2012-01-24 18:37:31.297 CLIXMPLParser[12658:707] initWithData 2: OK
```